# Django combine 2 Dictionary/Queryset that have same value

Tags: python, django

I Have the following two model queryset, and I want to combine that have same value, Could you please have your suggestions on this??, any help will be appreciated.
i already try this but not same what i want

1. after= list(chain(q1, q2))
2. after= q1 | q2

## my model

```
class BuildingCell(models.Model): 
    ...

class InputCutSew(models.Model): 

    cell = models.ForeignKey(BuildingCell, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL) 

class Absent(models.Model): 

    cell = models.ForeignKey(BuildingCell, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

```py
#this is my queryset
    q1= InputCutSew.objects.filter(publish='2019-07-22', days='normal', user=factory_user_cutting).exclude(cell_name__isnull=True).exclude(
         cell_name__exact='').order_by('cell').values('cell', 'model').annotate(
         total_output_jam=Sum(Case(When(dummy_days='normal', then='output'))),
         total_output_ot=Sum(Case(When(dummy_days='overtime', then='output'))),
         total_time=Sum('time'),
         total_time_ot=Sum('time_ot'),
         total_time_ot1=Sum('time_ot1'),
         total_time_ot2=Sum('time_ot2'),
         total_time_ot3=Sum('time_ot3'))
    q2 = Absent.objects.filter(publish='2019-07-22', building_name='f2', bagian='CUT').values('cell', 'normal_mp', 'ot0_mp', 'ot1_mp', 'ot2_mp', 'ot3_mp').exclude(cell__occult_cell='yes')

#dictionary from my query set
q1 = [
    {'cell': 633, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None},
    {'cell': 634, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None},
    {'cell': 635, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None},
    {'cell': 636, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None},
    {'cell': 637, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None},
    {'cell': 638, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None},
    {'cell': 639, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None},
    {'cell': 640, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None},
    {'cell': 641, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None},
    {'cell': 642, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None},
    {'cell': 644, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None},
    {'cell': 645, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None}
]

q2 = [
    {'cell': 633, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 634, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 635, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 636, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 637, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 638, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 639, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 640, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 641, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 642, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 644, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 645, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None}
]

the result what i want
after = [
    {'cell': 633, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 634, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 635, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 636, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 637, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 638, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 639, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 640, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 641, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 642, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 644, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None},
    {'cell': 645, 'model': 'superstar', 'total_output_jam': 240, 'total_output_ot': 90, 'total_time': Decimal('7.920'), 'total_time_ot': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot1': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot2': Decimal('0.990'), 'total_time_ot3': None, 'normal_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot0_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot1_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot2_mp': Decimal('30.000'), 'ot3_mp': None}
]
```

## updated problem solved

I get the result that I want by annotating a BuildingCell queryset

```
q3 =  BuildingCell.objects.filter(absent__publish='2019-07-22', absent__building_name='f2', absent__bagian='CUT', inputcutsew__publish='2019-07-22', inputcutsew__days='normal', inputcutsew__user=factory_user_cutting).exclude(inputcutsew__cell_name__isnull=True).exclude(
         inputcutsew__cell_name__exact='').order_by('inputcutsew__cell').values('inputcutsew__cell', 'inputcutsew__model', 'absent__cell', 'absent__normal_mp', 'absent__ot0_mp', 'absent__ot1_mp', 'absent__ot2_mp', 'absent__ot3_mp').exclude(occult_cell='yes').annotate(
         total_output_jam=Sum(Case(When(inputcutsew__dummy_days='normal', then='inputcutsew__output'))),
         total_output_ot=Sum(Case(When(inputcutsew__dummy_days='overtime', then='inputcutsew__output'))),
         total_time=Sum('inputcutsew__time'),
         total_time_ot=Sum('inputcutsew__time_ot'),
         total_time_ot1=Sum('inputcutsew__time_ot1'),
         total_time_ot2=Sum('inputcutsew__time_ot2'),
         total_time_ot3=Sum('inputcutsew__time_ot3'))
```

Comment: These aren't querysets, they are dictionaries. Is that what you meant?

Comment: yes dictionary from my queryset

Comment: Probably easier to share you models/queries and do this at the query level rather than modify dictionaries

Comment: yes i already updated my post, please see above

Comment: Both your models have a "cell" field, is this a foreign key?

Comment: yes cell field is a foreign key from other model,

Comment: Can you share the Cell, InputCutSew and Absent models?

Comment: class BuildingCell(models.Model):
class InputCutSew(models.Model):
    cell = models.ForeignKey(BuildingCell, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
class Absent(models.Model):
    cell = models.ForeignKey(BuildingCell, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

Comment: please see my post

Comment: It seems like there is only 1 `InputCutSew` and 1 `Absent` per `BuildingCell`? You can get the result that you want by annotating a `BuildingCell` queryset

Comment: Try using update() method of dictionary for merge two dictionaries.

Comment: thanks bro please see my updated post

Comment: @Iain Shelvington THANKS BRO problem solved

Answer (score 1):

try this way ,

```
list1 = [{'id': "1", "name": "xoxo"}, {'id': "2", "name": "yoyo"}]
list2 = [{'id': "1", "age": "11"}, {'id': "2", "age": "12"}]

list3 = []

for index,value in enumerate(list1):
    z = list1[index].copy()
    z.update(list2[index])
    list3.append(z)

print(list3)
```

**output**

```
[{'id': '1', 'name': 'xoxo', 'age': '11'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'yoyo', 'age': '12'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Uses SQL’s UNION operator to combine the results of two or more QuerySets.

try this

```
q1 = Model1.objects.all()

q2 = Model2.objects.all()

q3 = q1.union(q2)
```

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#union)

hope it helps

Comment: this is my result =====>each UNION query must have the same number of columns
LINE 1: ...s" FROM "adminfactory_inputcutsew") UNION (SELECT "absent_ab...